# Pasar de un fragmento a otro

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-asynctask

Me gustaría saber como puedo pasar del un fragmento a otro sin que me monte los dos en el contenedor, a continuación mi código.

Actividad donde esta el contenedor y llamo al primer fragmento:

```
public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.ejemplo, new Reloj()).commit();
    }
}
```

el fragmento llamado, al cual quiero pasar segundo fragmento  pero me monta los dos en el contenedor:

```
public class Reloj extends Fragment {

    private FButton sesion1;
    private FButton sesion2;
    String horaServr = "";
    TextView txtCurrentTime;
    TextView hora;
    TextView empiezaJAVA;
    int horas;
    Videoss videoss;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public Reloj() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reloj, container, false);
        sesion1 = (FButton)view.findViewById(R.id.botonXML);
        sesion2 = (FButton)view.findViewById(R.id.boton2XML);
         txtCurrentTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hora);
         hora = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hora2);
         empiezaJAVA = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.empieza);

        Servicios1 hiloconexion;
        String IP = "http://pasennova.esy.es/pausas_activas/juego";
        String LOGIN = IP + "/hora.php";
        hiloconexion = new Servicios1();
        String cadenallamada = LOGIN;
        hiloconexion.execute(cadenallamada, "2");

        return view;

    }public class Servicios1 extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        String evaluar ="";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String cadena = params[0];
            URL url = null;
            String devuelve = "";
            if (params[1].equals("2"))//Entrar
            {
                try
                {
                    evaluar="2";
                    url = new URL(cadena);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" + " (Linux; Android 5.1; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");
                    int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                    {
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            result.append(line);
                        }
                        JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                        String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");
                        devuelve = devuelve + resultJSON;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return devuelve;
            }
            return devuelve;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String s) {
            super.onCancelled(s);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            horaServr = s;
            if (horaServr.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error de conexion"+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            if (horaServr.equals(null))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error de conexion"+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Thread myThread = null;
                Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
                myThread = new Thread(runnable);
                myThread.start();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

    public void doWork() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            public void run() {
                try {


                    sesion1.setEnabled(false);
                    sesion2.setEnabled(false);
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int segundos = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    int minutos = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int horas = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    Date dt = new Date();
                    int horas2 = dt.getHours();
                    int minutos2 = dt.getMinutes();
                    int segundos2 = dt.getSeconds();
                    String curTime = horas2 + ":" + minutos2 + ":" + segundos2;
                    hora.setText(curTime);
                    String horaTelefono = String.valueOf(horas);
                    if (horaServr.equals(horaTelefono)) {
                        if (horas2 < 12) {
                            String tiempo = horas + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos+" AM";
                            txtCurrentTime.setText(tiempo);
                            if (horas2 <= 10) {
                                if ((horas2 == 10) || (horas2 == 11) || (horas2 == 12)) {
                                    sesion1.setEnabled(true);
                                    empiezaJAVA.setText("La rutina de la mañana la puede realizar");
                                    sesion1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            videoss = new Videoss();
                                            FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                                            FragmentTransaction trans2 =fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();
                                            trans2.replace(R.id.ejemplo,videoss);
                                            trans2.commit();
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    sesion1.setEnabled(false);
                                    int horasFaltante = 9 - horas2;
                                    int minutosFaltante = 60 - minutos2;
                                    int segundosFaltante = 60 - segundos2;
                                    //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    empiezaJAVA.setText("su rutina empieza: " + horasFaltante + ":" + minutosFaltante + ":" + segundosFaltante);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            String tiempo = horas + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos+ " PM";
                            txtCurrentTime.setText(tiempo);
                            if ((horas2 == 16) || (horas2 == 17) || (horas2 == 18)) {
                                sesion2.setEnabled(true);
                                empiezaJAVA.setText("La rutina de la tarde la puede realizar");
                                sesion2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        videoss = new Videoss();
                                       FragmentTransaction tras = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                        tras.replace(R.id.ejemplo, new Videoss());
                                        tras.commit();
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                sesion2.setEnabled(false);
                                int horasFaltante = (15 - horas2);
                                int minutosFaltante = (60 - minutos2);
                                int segundosFaltante = (60 - segundos2);
                                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rutnias empiza en: " + horasFaltante + ":" + minutosFaltante + ":" + segundosFaltante, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                empiezaJAVA.setText("Rutnias empiza en: " + horasFaltante + ":" + minutosFaltante + ":" + segundosFaltante);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        empiezaJAVA.setText("Actualiza el reloj de tu movil");
                        sesion1.setEnabled(false);
                        sesion2.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        });
    }
    class CountDownRunner implements Runnable{
        // @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                try {
                    doWork();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es utilizar la función de replace esta función como su nombre lo indica reemplaza en vez de agregar otro fragment tambien podrías agregarlo al backtack si quieres. pero con el replace debería ser suficiente en tu caso aquí un ejemplo:

```
 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ejemplo, new Reloj()).commit();
```

Recuerda que R.id.ejemplo es el id de tu contenedor de fragments por lo cual deberías tener un nombre mas descriptivo para el mismo.

Comment: si me funciono perfecto.... una otra pregunta tu por casualidad sabes colocar proxy al emulador android ?

Comment: no entiendo bien la pregunta pero si quieres crea otra pregunta aqui en stack y veo si logro ayudarte saludos.

Answer (score 4):

> el fragmento llamado, al cual quiero pasar segundo fragmento pero me
>   monta los dos en el contenedor.

Se están encimando ya que estas agregando un fragmento por medio del método **[.add()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment))** y no un reemplazo del fragmento mediante **[.replace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment))**:

```
 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.ejemplo, new Reloj()).commit();
```

---

La solución es que asegures realizar la transacción de fragmentos en el mismo contenedor, siempre mediante **[.replace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment))**.

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment).commit();
```

Con esto reemplazarías el fragmento sin problema!

Answer (score 1):

```
                Fragmento_a_donde_quieres_ir fragmento = new Fragmento_a_donde_quieres_ir();
                FragmentManager manejador = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manejador.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.contenedor2, fragmento).commit();
```