# pasar a un fragmet mediante un bottonbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, botón

el problema es el siguente tengo una activiy y en esa activity tengo un `buttonBar` , cuando intento pasar a en `fragment` mediante el cliqueo de un boton del buttonBar me da error.

Este es el codigo

```
    public class ElectricalCalculators extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {


   Button kwbutton , evbutton ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_electrical_calculators);



        findViewById(R.id.menu_back).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.menu_home).setOnClickListener(this);


        Button kwbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ampsBoutton);
        kwbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( v.getContext() , AmpsConversion.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });


        Button evbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.evBoutton);
        evbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( v.getContext() , ElectronVoltsConversion.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });


        Button jbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.joulesBoutton);
        jbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( v.getContext() , JoulesConversion.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });


        Button Kwbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kwBoutton);
        Kwbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( v.getContext() , KwConversion.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });



        Button Kwhbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kwhBoutton);
        Kwhbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( v.getContext() , KwhConversion.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Class clazz = null;

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();



        if (v.getId() == R.id.menu_back){

           fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.elctricalCalculator,  new Fragmen2()).commit();



        }


       /** switch (v.getId()) {


            case R.id.menu_back:

                //clazz = Fragmen2.class;
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.elctricalCalculator,  new Fragmen2()).commit();


                break;

            case R.id.menu_home:
                clazz = MainActivity.class;
                break;
            /**case R.id.five_tabs_changing_colors:
             clazz = FiveColorChangingTabsActivity.class;
             break;*/

        //}


//        startActivity(new Intent(this, clazz));

    }
}
```

y el error es :

```
ATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.example.liantonypozo.calculos, PID: 10048
                                                                                           android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3/com.example.liantonypozo.calculos.Fragmen2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
                                                                                               at com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3.ElectricalCalculators.onClick(ElectricalCalculators.java:97)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el error, este indica que no se ha registrado en el `AndroidManifest.xml` la `Activity` `Fragmen2` :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3/com.example.liantonypozo.calculos.Fragmen2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

agrega la actividad dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` para que quede registrada en tu aplicacion.

```
  <application
     ...
      ...
      <activity android:name=".Fragmen2"/>
  </application>
```

---

¿El nombre de la `Activity` es `Fragment2`? si en verdad es una `Activity` y extiende de `Activity` o `AppCompatActivity`,  esta debe abrirse sin problema al abrir la Activity mediante `startActivity()`:

```
  clazz = Fragmen2.class;
  startActivity(new Intent(this, clazz));
```

---

Si tu clase `Fragmen2.class` es un `Fragment`, tienes que realizar una transacción.

[Pasar de un fragmento a otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33234/pasar-de-un-fragmento-a-otro/33282#33282)

Comment: tengo entendido que los Fragment no se agregan en el android manifest ?

Comment: Entonces si es un Fragment, no se puede abrir mediante un Intent. @LiantonyPozo ese es el problema.

Comment: Entonces en ese caso como lo puedo usar con el bottonbar?

Comment: como comento en mi respuesta, si es un Fragmento tienes que realizar una transacción,no usar un Intent es lo que comento aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65655/cambiar-de-un-fragment-a-otro-por-medio-de-un-boton/65657#65657

Comment: utilice ese método , el problema es que se superpone  encima del activity el fragment se visualizan los dos al mismo tiempo

Comment: "se visualizan los dos al mismo tiempo" debes realizar un replace() de fragments, agrega tu código o abre otra pregunta y te ayudo.

Comment: ya agregué el código que estoy utilizando , tengo el replace() pero es igual

Comment: @LiantonyPozo tienes definido un Fragment en elctricalCalculator

Comment: electicalCalculator es un activity  , y el fragment es independiente